# Table with input text created by jquery how to save in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

### Please help me how to save in mysql database an inputted data in my dynamic table.

This is the html file.

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>CodePen - Dynamic Table</title>

  <link href="dynamictable_css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<body>

  <div id="main">
  <h1>Data Table</h1>
  <table id="data" class="data-table data-table-horizontal data-table-highlight">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><a type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
    
  </table>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="top-buffer" onclick="addRow('data')" />
  </div>
</div>

  <script src="dynamictable_js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is javascript.

> index.js:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newRow = row.insertCell(i);

    newRow.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    newRow.childNodes[0].value = "";
  }
}
 
function deleteRow(row) {
  var table = document.getElementById("data");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  if (rowCount > 1) {
    var rowIndex = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("data").deleteRow(rowIndex);
  }
  else {
    alert("Please specify at least one value.");
  }
}
```

This is the css.

> style.css:

```
h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #666;
}

.data-table {
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.data-table tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.data-table-highlight tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.data-table-horizontal tbody td {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.top-buffer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

#main {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

I have a thesis from Bulacan State University in philippines.
I am 4th year IT student want to pass my thesis.

Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Where is your PHP code to save the data on button click? You need [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), I guess.

Comment: i dont have php code. so please give me how to save that in mysql database,thanks

Comment: You haven't used PHP, You haven't used Ajax, then how on earth you're going to save the data in your MySQL table? I think you're a beginner in PHP and MySQL. Please check some tutorials before asking questions here. Here's a tutorial on `insert` : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: I have a knowledge in saving in database but  I tried several methods like saving multple value using for each but nothings work.

Comment: You have not provided any PHP code that saves records into your MySQL table. And now you're asking how to do it from scratch. These sort of questions doesn't belong on SO. This is not a tutorial site. Show us where you're exactly stuck with only the relevant code; don't just copy and paste your entire project's code here.